# How do I print the elements in vector that correspond to another array?

Tags: c++, vector

Lets say i have this code:

```
struct info{
    int num;
    int position;
    vector<int> vDigits;
    vector<string> vCode;

}
int main(){

    info info[2];    //
    info[0].num = 1234;
    info[1].num = 5678;

    //I do some calculations and call some functions for info[0]. What the functions
    do is they split every digit in '1234' and store them in vDigits and store position
    as 0(since its the first input) and a unique string is assigned to each digit and 
    stored vCode.
    // Same functions are applied to info[1] and position is stored as 1



}
```

My question is how can i print the digits and its code based on the position? without using any data structure

I want to print:

```
pos: 0, digit: 1, code: "one"
pos: 0, digit: 2, code: "two"
pos: 0, digit: 3, code: "three"
pos: 0, digit: 4, code: "four"
pos: 1, digit: 5, code: "five"
pos: 1, digit: 6, code: "six"
pos: 1, digit: 7, code: "seven"
pos: 1, digit: 8, code: "eight"
```

Comment: Why "_without using any data structure_"? Do you count a `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>` as a data structure? Where do you get the `code`s from?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Just the printing of the data as you have shown? Are you required to store all that information in the structure?

Comment: *without using any data structure* -- Even an array is a data structure, thus you can't basically write any meaningful program without some sort of data structure.   In short, "without using any data structure" are very vague "requirements".

Answer (score 1):

Overloading the `<<` operator

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, info const &inf) {
    for (int i = 0; i< inf.vDigits.size(); i++) {
        os << "pos: " << inf.position << ", digit: " << inf.vDigits[i] << ", code: " << '"' << inf.vCode[i] << '"';
    return os;
}
```

Then just:

```
std::cout << info[0] << info[1] << std::endl;
```